# Add entries to database table from a file

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add entries into my database table from a text file by using a PHP script. The text file contains 2000 lines and I want each line to be one entry in a database table. This is my code. It runs fine but nothing is added into the table.

```
<?php

$link = new mysqli('xxx.xxx.xxx.xx', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxx');
 if ($link->connect_errno) {
    die('Failed to connect to MySQL: (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
 }
 $filename = 'serials.txt';
 $file = file($filename);
 foreach($file as $line) {
   $result = $link->query("INSERT INTO mytable SET serial=$line");
 }
?>
```

Comment: Why not use LOAD DATA?

Comment: I never heard of it and have no idea how to use it

Comment: So, now would be a good time to learn, don't you think?

Comment: What datatype is `serial`? If it's a string, you need to put `$line` in quotes.

Comment: If you have phpmyadmin installed you can use the 'Import' button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Print the error-messages
2. [escape](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) the data

```php
<?php

$link = new mysqli('xxx.xxx.xxx.xx', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxx');
 if ($link->connect_errno) {
    die('Failed to connect to MySQL: (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
 }
 $filename = 'serials.txt';
 $file = file($filename);
 foreach($file as $line) {
   $result = $link->query("INSERT INTO mytable SET serial='"
            .$link->real_escape_string($line)."'");
   if($link->errno) echo($link->errno.": ".$link->error);
 }
?>
```